# Can you specify the number of threads for certain tasks in a DAG?

Tags: airflow

I'm very new to Airflow and while I have read the docs and some answers about Airflow's configuration regarding parallelism, it seems I have not yet found the answer to specifying threads used in a task.

My current case is I have 5 tasks (in the form of a Python script) that only do API calls (but to different API service) and transform the data. For each task I can make up to 1000+ calls, so I try to utilize multithreading in the script. Unfortunately, when I try to run the multithreaded script in Airflow, it doesn't use the multithreading mechanism in the script. I feel like this is because of Airflow configuration that overrides the child script or am I wrong? Any help or answer is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run your script with a [KubernetesPodOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#howto-operator-kubernetespodoperator).

You can use a python base image and run your script as is. This should closely mimic how you are executing the script locally except now it's done in a kubernetes pod.

Comment: Ah I should have put more information. We are not yet running on a cluster, just a single machine so we are using LocalExecutor with PythonOperator.